# Using generator recursive combination algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, generator, combinations

I was practicing algorithm questions from https://sahandsaba.com/combinatorial-generation-for-coding-interviews-in-python.html#exercises.
I am trying to do 4.4.4 which simply changes the solution below to using generators. I was successful in doing so, but I don't understand it. Could someone explain to me whats happening?

1. Here is the solution provided to generate combinations:

   ```
   def strings(A, n):
       if n == 0:
          return ['']
       return [s + c for s in strings(A, n - 1) for c in A]
   ```
2. Here is the readable solution:

   ```
   def strings(A, n):
       if n == 0:
           return [""]
       temp_list = list()
       for s in strings(A, n-1):
           for c in A:
               temp_list.append(s+c)
       return temp_list
   ```
3. This is my attempt using generators instead. However, it results in a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

   ```
   def strings(A, n):
       if n == 0:
           yield ""
       for s in strings(A, n-1):
           for c in A:
               yield s + c
   ```
4. If add `return` after `yield ""`, it works. My question is why does it work?

   ```
   def strings(A, n):
       if n == 0:
          yield ""
          return 
       for s in strings(A, n-1):
           for c in A:
              yield s + c
   ```

Comment: because without it you are going to the `for`-loop

Comment: It works because you provide a termination to recursion, the base. Otherwise you keep going through the loop endlessly after checking n is zero

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand now. I forgot that after the yields return, it will return back and  run any code after.

Comment: In 3 and 4, the `for` loops should be in an `else` block to prevent going through the usual recursive part of your code all over again, infinitely. You can then remove the `return` in 4.

Comment: @aneroid, I like that solution. It would make it more readable to more users.

Comment: Using `return` does allow you to reduce the indent of the block following it, and looks slightly better; but _`return` behaves differently inside a generator_. Example, in this generator function: `def f(): yield 1; yield 2; return 3`, the last `3` won't actually be returned as a value, it works purely as a control flow statement. So `list(f())` returns `[1, 2]`.